# How to make a aspect-ratio preserving resizable div with only css or webkit vendor-specific css

Tags: resize, css

I'm making a Chrome web app using the flexible box model, but I've gotten stuck on a (horizontal) scrollable window where I have a whole bunch of featured items.

I want to make the featured items have a constant aspect ratio, but I want them to be able to size with the rest of the page. The space that the featured items take up is 30% of height.

Any ideas to get this done? ( I can provide more information, but I'm just not where sure to start. Add a comment if you need more info and I'll edit this question).